# How can I tell if a node is in memory or in the dom?

Tags: jquery, dom

I am working a lot with nodes before they are attached to the main page's DOM; and I need to perform some work depending on whether or not a given node is contained within the main document or not.

My current method is to walk up the parents, via:

```
if this.el$.closest("body").length > 0
```

Is there a more appropriate way to do this?  (Preferrably one that doesn't have to walk all of the node's ancestors?)

Comment: Well it will vary by how deep down I am in the tree, I don't know what I have in store for this project I could be doing some crazy shit and be super far down, results will vary :)

Comment: It definitely would be interesting to see if there's a more appropriate way of testing this, rather than having to walk the node's ancestry every time

Comment: what about just `.parent()`? I just did a quick test and an element in memory had no parent. Or even quicker would be javascript's `.parentNode`

Comment: @MrOBrian I'm fairly certain that when you call `appendChild` on an in-memory node it will set the `parent` of the appended node normally. If the OP is building trees in memory, that won't be enough.

Comment: See [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/javascript-check-if-element-exists-in-the-dom), I think the solution there would be faster

Comment: @MrOBrian: You are indeed correct, the method added in the  linked solution is slightly faster and I added it to my tests for completeness. Thanks for the info and the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several options which execute at several different speeds.

```
var $document = $(document);
var $element = $("#jq-footer");
var exists;

// Test if the element is within a body
exists = $element.closest("body").length;

// Test if the document contains an element
// wrong syntax, use below instead --> exists = $.contains($document, $element);
exists = $.contains(document.documentElement, $element[0]);

// Test if the element is within a body
$($element).parents().is("body");

// Manually loop trough the elements
exists = elementExists($element[0]);

// Used for manual loop
function elementExists(element) {
    while (element) {
        if (element == document) {
            return true;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}​
```

See [**Performance Test**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/4vaFw/1/)

For this test I copied a huge amount of html to traverse over, I copied the source of one of the jQuery pages into a fiddle, stripping out all the script tags leaving only the body and the html in between.

Feel free you use document instead of "body" and vice-versa or add more tests but it should give you the general idea.

**Edit**

I updated the performance test to use the correct syntax for [**contains**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) as the previous one was incorrect and always returned true even if the element did not exist. the blow now returns true if the element exists but if you specify a selector which doesn't exist it will return false.

```
exists = $.contains(document.documentElement, $element[0]);
```

I also added the suggested alternative mentioned by **MrOBrian** in the comments of the question which is again slightly faster than contains.

Nice one **MrOBrian**.

**Edit**

Here is the jsPerf [**performance test**](http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-contains) with all the nice charts.

Thanks **Felix Kling** for spotting the issue and helping me fix the jsPerf tests.

Added more test results from the comments, this one is really good:
jsPerf performance test: [**dom-tree-test-exists**](http://jsperf.com/dom-tree-test-exists)

Comment: Awesome!  `$.contains` looks like the way to go

Comment: You might be interested in this jsPerf comparison: http://jsperf.com/dom-tree-test

Comment: @FelixKling: I tried setting up jsPerf but got `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'compareDocumentPosition'.` when trying to execute the contains code. Here is the link to the failing test: `http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-contains` Not sure how to fix it. So I resorted to time stamping in fiddle instead :)

Comment: The problem was that you passed to jQuery objects to `$.contains`, not DOM nodes...

Comment: @FelixKling: Awesome, I fixed the tests up now and added them to the answer, the more info the better. Thanks and well spotted.

Comment: @Jonathan: According to [this test](http://jsperf.com/dom-tree-test-exists), ID lookup for attached elements is even faster than `$.contains` in Chrome. And in Firefox, using `document.body.contains` seems to be a lot faster than anything else.

Comment: @FelixKling: Nice find, I will add this to the answer as well. Very very good information.

Comment: `document.body.contains` is crazy-fast (3-4x faster) on Safari 6 and iOS 6, as well

Answer (score 13):

The modern, vanilla answer is to use [`Node.isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected):

```js
let test = document.createElement('p');
console.log(test.isConnected); // Returns false
document.body.appendChild(test);
console.log(test.isConnected); // Returns true
```

(example taken directly from the MDN docs)

Answer (score 4):

You could assign an ID to the element and then search for it:

```
var id = element.id || generateRandomId(); // some function generating a random string
if(document.getElementById(id) !== null) {
    // element in tree
}
```

Here is a [**performance comparison**](http://jsperf.com/dom-tree-test) including François' suggestions, comparing each method for an attached and detached element node. [Here are the test cases](http://jsperf.com/dom-tree-test-exists) for only existing nodes, to get a better idea for the speed difference.

**Test results:**

Obviously testing a detached node with the `while` is faster, since it terminates nearly instantly (at the second iteration). But if the node has a (potentially) detached ancestor, then assigning an ID to the node and look for it seems to be the fastest way in Chrome 21.

Interestingly though, in Firefox 14, the [`Node#contains` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.contains) method seems to be much faster than anything else.

Since the speed improvements in Firefox from ID lookup to native `.contains` seems to be higher than the performance loss in Chrome, a fast function could look like this:

```
function in_tree(element) {
    if(!element || !element.parentNode) { // fail fast
        return false;
    }
    if(element.contains) {
        return document.body.contains(element);
    }
    var id = element.id || generateRandomId();
    element.id = id;
    return document.getElementById(id) !== null;
}
```

But in the end, there will always be differences between browsers, so you have to make a compromise.