# Check if a DOM element node actually exists in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm defining a function that should receive a DOM element node as a parameter.

**There is any efficient way to validate if the element node received actually exists in the DOM?**

For example if the element node received has been created through [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) but not appended to the DOM, I want the validation fails.

I already accomplished it with the code below, but I'm afraid that checking for all DOM element nodes is not the best solution for performance.

```
function checkIfNodeExists(nodeElement) {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll("*")].includes(nodeElement);
}
```

**Could someone suggest a better solution or convince me that my solution is already appropriate?**

Comment: Another similar question that might be helpful: [How can I tell if a node is in memory or in the dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943441/how-can-i-tell-if-a-node-is-in-memory-or-in-the-dom) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63794198/14956277) for [`Node.isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if an element is in the DOM? You can see if it is in the body.

```js
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
var div2 = document.querySelector("#foo");


console.log(document.body.contains(div1))
console.log(document.body.contains(div2))
```

```html
<div id="foo"><div>
```