# Checking if an element created by javascript exists using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The question is quite straightforward. Is there a javascript only (no jQuery/other library pls) method of checking if an element created via javascript exists?

For instance, if I did this:

```
var foo=document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById("bar").appendChild(foo);
```

Would there be a way to check if foo already exists?

Comment: If you don't give it an id or unique class, no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom

Comment: What is an element that does not exist? Is this a philosophical question?

Comment: @AvinashBabu, that isn't what I was looking for. infantDev's answer, however, did provide me with what I needed.

Comment: What do you mean, check if foo already exists? The variable `foo` holds a *brand new element* that you just created; there is no way it could have already existed before calling `document.createElement`, because `document.createElement` always creates a new element.

Comment: @DaggNabbit If I were to run the function again it would create another foo, which is not something wanted.

Comment: @user2644333 yes, it would create *another* element. It wouldn't "re-create" an element that "already exists." It would create *a different element*. The way your question is worded, it is pretty much meaningless, to the point where answerers need to *guess at what you mean*.

Comment: Why would an element you just created *not* exist? This question sounds like you experienced an error, and decided on this as a solution. What was the original problem? Because, as noted elsewhere, the question as phrased seems redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply get the element by id and see if its not null.

```
var foo=document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById("bar").appendChild(foo);
foo.setAttribute("id","foo");
var ele = document.getElementById("foo");
if(ele !== null){ alert("Hi");}
```

Comment: This answer introduces an assumption not made by the OP, which is that the element has an ID.

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is not an element, it's a variable whose value is an element. There are different ways to interpret your question.

#### Is the value of the variable `foo` a DOM element?

If you want to check if the variable `foo` exists and has as its value an element, you can say

```
foo && typeof foo === 'object' && foo.nodeType
```

or something similar. This will check whether the element is any kind of `Node`. To check for an element, use `foo.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE`.

#### Is a particular HTML element in the DOM?

If you want to check if the element held in variable `foo` is in the DOM, as opposed to having been created, but not yet inserted, then:

```
foo.baseURI
```

since `baseURI` is set only upon DOM insertion. You might think you could check `parentNode`, which is also not set until DOM insertion, but children of the non-inserted element, if any, will report a `parentNode`, as will elements appended to a document fragment.

The other alternative is to use `Node#contains`:

```
document.body.contains(foo)
```

which essentially does the same thing as scanning the entire DOM for the element:

```
Array.prototype.some.call(document.querySelector('*'), function(elt) {
    return elt === foo;
})
```

In any case, this all seems pointless, because as far as I can imagine, if you hold a reference to a DOM element, and it's not *not* in the DOM, then it **is** in the DOM.

#### Is there already an element in the place I'm going to be inserting this one?

If you know where the element is going to go, in this case as a child of `bar`, and that's enough to convince you that the "element already exists", you can check easily enough with something like:

```
document.getElementById("bar").children.length > 0
```

#### Is there already an element with this ID?

As other commenters and responders have noted, you can obviously find an element in the DOM if you have arranged to provide it with some uniquely identifiable characteristics, most likely an id.

I hope it's obvious that element ID is completely separate from the name of any JavaScript variables which happen to be holding references to that element. It is true that elements become available on the root (window) object under their ID or name attributes, a feature best left unused.

#### Was the element in the source HTML, or created by JavaScript?

From the wording of your question, it seems that you *might* be interested in whether the element was created by JS, as opposed to originating from the source HTML. There is no way I know of to detect that. If you are intent on doing so, override `document.createElement` as follows:

```
document.createElement = (function() {
    var old = document.createElement;
    return function(tagName) {
        var elt = old.call(document, tagName);
        elt.I_CREATED_THIS = true;
        return elt;
    };
}());

> document.body.I_CREATED_THIS
undefined
> elt = document.createElement('span');
> elt.I_CREATED_THIS
true
```

Comment: `I hope it's obvious that element ID is completely separate from the name of any JavaScript variables which happen to be holding references to that element.` -- actually IDs do become global variables, see [section 7.2.4](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) of the HTML5 spec. Hard to tell whether it's relevant to the OP's problem, since the question is nonsense as it's worded now.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Thanks for reminding me of that. I'll tweak my answer.