# What is the best way to know if an element is in the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if a certain element is in the document.

I tried two options and i want to know which one is the best in terms of resources.

1)

```
var $lastParent = $(element).parents().last();
var nodeName = $lastParent.prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
var isInDocument = (nodeName == 'html');
```

2)

```
var isInDocument = document.contains(element);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: Check for its length?

Comment: if the selector doesnt return null , then it exists.

Comment: @ProllyGeek A jQuery object is never null.

Comment: @Juhana you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`document.contains`

or

`document.body.contains()`

checkout eht `IsInPage` implementation here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains

- Many more ways here: [How to check if element exists in the visible DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom/16820058#16820058) `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if ($(element).length) return true;`

Comment: `.length` is not a function.