# How to check if DOM reference has been destroyed?

Tags: javascript, dom

Say I select an element the old fashioned way (*or any other way by which a DOM reference might be obtained*):

```
var el = document.getElementById('myFavoriteElement');
```

Then I remove that element's parent from the DOM, thus removing `el` as well. Or I just remove `el` directly.

Is there a way to check whether `el` is still a valid reference, whether the HTML to which it refers still exists in the DOM? Something along the lines of `el.hasBeenDestroyed` as a boolean attribute, or something like that?

Comment: @blex no, that won't work. if you remove `el`, the reference to `el` still exists.

Comment: How about `document.contains(el);`? [From this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom)

Comment: One of the other answers will be more reliable and semantic, but just for fun I noticed that `getBoundingClientRect()` will often change to {0, 0, 0, 0} post-removal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `baseURI` attribute will be filled in if the element is on the page DOM. Check that.

Alternatively, try `document.body.contains(node)`.

**Edit:** Now in 2022, the DOM node `isConnected` readonly property provides this information. My experiment shows that the `baseURI` property remains filled even when removed from the DOM.

Comment: Works. Is probably more efficient than document.contains, too.

Answer (score 1):

Simply look for a parent.

```
function hasBeenDestroyed(el){ return !el.parentNode; }
```

#### Demo

```js
var el = document.getElementById('myDiv');
document.getElementById('destroyBtn').onclick = function(){ el.outerHTML = ''; };
document.getElementById('checkBtn').onclick = function(){
    if( hasBeenDestroyed(el) ) alert('The div has been destroyed');
    else alert('The div is still here');
};

function hasBeenDestroyed(el){ return !el.parentNode; }
```

```css
#myDiv{ padding: 1em; background: red; }
```

```html
<button id="destroyBtn">Destroy the div</button>
<button id="checkBtn">Check if div still exists</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: An element can have a parentNode but not inside the document. For example if you have a `<div>` that is not in the document but only as a DOM object, and it has a `<span>`, the `<span>` has a parentNode.

Comment: He's not asking if it's in the document. He's asking if the element (or one of its ancestors) has been destroyed. That's quite different. But I get your point, and yes, that function would not be valid in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using `document.contains(el);`.

```js
function removeSpan()
{
  var el = document.getElementById("test");
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  document.getElementById("exist").innerHTML = document.contains(el);
}
```

```html
<div>This is a div. <span id="test">This is a span</span></div>
<button type="button" onclick="removeSpan();">Remove span</button>
<div>Does the span exist? <span id="exist">true</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check whether it has been destroyed, but you can check whether it is still in the document node.

```
function inDocument(el) {
    var parentNode = el.parentNode;
    while (parentNode) {
        if (parentNode === document) {
            return true;
        }
        parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sure, but you could streamline this by saying `while (el) { if (el === document) return true; el = el.parentNode; }`.