# Dynamic controls with skipped sequence in ID

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding some controls dynamically to a HTML page using JavaScript. Lets say I have this

```
ID   Name          Type                   Is Valid
     (TextBox)     (Select/DropDown)      (CheckBox)
---  ------------  ---------------------  ----------
1    txtName_1     ddlType_1              chkValid_1
2    txtName_2     ddlType_2              chkValid_2
3    txtName_3     ddlType_3              chkValid_3
4    txtName_4     ddlType_4              chkValid_4
```

Now I remove some rows (e.g. row with ID 3) and add some new rows. New controls are named as ("txtName_" + "Last Row ID" + 1). So it may become

```
ID   Name          Type                   Is Valid
     (TextBox)     (Select/DropDown)      (CheckBox)
---  ------------  ---------------------  ----------
1    txtName_1     ddlType_1              chkValid_1
2    txtName_2     ddlType_2              chkValid_2
4    txtName_4     ddlType_4              chkValid_4
5    txtName_5     ddlType_5              chkValid_5
```

Now I want to iterate these controls in a for loop (1 to "Last Row ID") to generate a concatenated string. **How these deleted IDs can be skipped in the loop?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying the concept in this SO post [How to check if element exists in the visible DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5629761/5104101), the controls IDs with skipped numbers can be checked as follows in the loop

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= lastRowID; i++;)
{
    var element =  document.getElementById('txtName'+i);
    if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
    {
        // control with this ID exists.
    } else {
        // control with this ID does NOT exist, SKIP it.
    }
}
```