# javascript variables on different pages

Tags: javascript

Lets say i have 2 html pages ( home & about ), inside the home page i have a header like so

```
<header id="#header">
  some code
</header>
```

and this header is only on the home page so if i selected this header in java script main file

```
const header = document.getElementById('#header');
```

it's going to give me an error on about page because there is no such a thing as header in this page, so how do you prevent those kind of errors ? 
do I have to make it a local variable instead ?

what I actually made is something like this

```
if( body.className = 'home' ) {
 some code
}
```

like this I will be sure that about page won't have access to anything that related to the home page, but is this is a bad practice ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom

Comment: `const header = document.getElementById('#header');` should just give a null result. You can test `if (header)` before using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *many* ways that this could be improved. The most direct answer to your question though is that `document.getElementById` returns `null` if the element is not found. So put any code that depends on `header` in a conditional that checks for `null`.

```
if (header) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ternary operator in javascript like

```
const header = document.getElementById('#header')?document.getElementById('#header'):null;
```

Hence it will not give error,
and wherever you want to use it you can use a null check using if statement.

Comment: This is not a great use of the ternary operator. This same line would be better reduced to `const header = document.getElementById('#header') || null;`, but this is still unnecessary because `document.getElementById` either returns a DOM node or `null` itself.