# Mapbox is not loading on all pages?

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

Mapbox is being used across the site, however, isn't loading on two specific pages?

There are three maps, all of which display fine on [this page](https://www.physiofive.co.uk/our-clinics). And [here](https://www.physiofive.co.uk/our-clinics/stroud) is a working example of the page I am looking to replicate elsewhere, only with a different map. However, on [this page](https://www.physiofive.co.uk/our-clinics/gloucester) the map doesn't load?

This is the javascript I'm using, each map has a different `var`, `stroud`, `gloucester` and `brimscombe`.

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'validtokenhere';

// STROUD
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Visit our Stroud clinic",
                "iconSize": [30, 40]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -2.248550,
                    51.741290
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
};

var stroud = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'stroud',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [-2.248550,51.741290],
    zoom: 13
});

// disable map zoom when using scroll
stroud.scrollZoom.disable();

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
    // create a DOM element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/assets/img/marker.png)';
    el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
    el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.alert(marker.properties.message);
    });

    // add marker to map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(stroud);
});

// GLOUCESTER
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Visit our Gloucester clinic",
                "iconSize": [30, 40]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -2.248140,
                    51.870560
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
};

var gloucester = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'gloucester',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [-2.248140,51.870560],
    zoom: 13
});

// disable map zoom when using scroll
gloucester.scrollZoom.disable();

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
    // create a DOM element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/assets/img/marker.png)';
    el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
    el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.alert(marker.properties.message);
    });

    // add marker to map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(gloucester);
});

// BRIMSCOMBE
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Visit our Brimscombe clinic",
                "iconSize": [30, 40]
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -2.063020,
                    51.892550
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
};

var brimscombe = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'brimscombe',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [-2.063020,51.892550],
    zoom: 13
});

// disable map zoom when using scroll
brimscombe.scrollZoom.disable();

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
    // create a DOM element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(/assets/img/marker.png)';
    el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
    el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.alert(marker.properties.message);
    });

    // add marker to map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(brimscombe);
});
```

and then each container is

```
<section class="location-map-image">
  <div id="stroud" class="map" style="width: 100%; height: 263px;"></div>
</section>
```

obviously the div id changes to match the location I wish to display.

I am expecting to see Gloucester and Brimscombe load like Stroud does?

Console log is showing

```
Error: Container 'stroud' not found. map.js:337:22
    r map.js:337
    <anonymous> app-min.js:12508
```

So it appears that the script gets stuck when it cannot find the div id `stroud`. What should I be doing when I only want to show `gloucester` or `brimscombe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL:DR; There is no HTML element for the map to render in

The error you're seeing is because there is no `div` tag on [this page](https://www.physiofive.co.uk/our-clinics/gloucester) with the id of `stroud` or `brimscombe`, so Mapbox doesn't know where to render the map.

[image: Gloucester page dev tools]

If you go to [the stroud clinic page](https://www.physiofive.co.uk/our-clinics/stroud), you'll notice that you get errors for `briscombe` and `gloucester`, because neither of those `div`s exist.

[image: Stroud page dev tools]

EDIT:

If you want to not see the errors, there are [a few different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom) you could do it, but I'd do it something like this:

```
// Checking if the element stroud exists
if (!!document.getElementById('stroud')) {
  // If it does, run the stroud code
}
```

You can repeat that pattern for your other two as well. No need to provide an `else` unless you want to.

Comment: Yes that's right, so I guess I need some kind of if statement, for example, if stroud, don't run briscombe or gloucester

Comment: @GrantSmith The errors won't cause any problems, but if you want to get rid of them, I added a simple `if` statement above. If you find the answer helpful, please accept it!