# Finding body element inside textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have `textarea` element. When a user types some HTML code inside the `textarea`, the function should find the `body` element.

The HTML code

```
<textarea id="textarea_code" ></textarea>
<a href="" onclick="check()">Check element</a>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
function check()
{
var codecheck = document.getElementById('teatarea_code').getElementsByTagName('body');

 if(codecheck)
 {
 alert('Yes, textarea has body element.');
 }
}
```

Comment: html code is missing and whats exactly is the query?

Comment: You might find [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) useful. Also see [Parse an HTML string with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if element exists in the visible DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale It seems that the element is not in the DOM. It's a string entered into a `<textarea>`.

Comment: @showdev Vote Extracted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future search the web for either "string in string" or "string substring".

```
if (document.getElementById('textarea_code').value.indexOf('<body') > -1)
{
 alert('Yes, textarea has body element.');
}
```

As a proper (and semi-dynamic) function:

```
function substring_search(e,ss)
{
 //e = element
 //ss = substring

 return (document.getElementById(e).value.indexOf(ss) > -1) ? true : false;
}
```

Also avoid camelCase, use underscores for code (and dashes for URLs) to both objectively and visually differentiate your code.

Comment: Thank you ! Now it works. I appreciate your suggestion and will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

The variable codecheck will not return true if there is content inside body tag, but will return true when there is a body tag which obviously is. So the function always gives an alert message irrespective of whether it has content inside the body tag or not until the body tag exists.

Comment: I only need to find, if the body tag exist or not ! However this code is not working

Comment: what do you want to check, whether body tag exists or the content inside it exists?

Comment: only body tag exists

Comment: just look at the source code, there is no need for any function. After all, you are only creating the page and why would you not know whether there is a body tag or not..

Answer (score 0):

In textarea we can check that it contains the substring or not

```
document.getElementById("myTextarea")value.includes('<body>').
```