# How to know if a value its an element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, element

as much as the question seems silly (and in fact it is) I didn't find the answer anywhere, only what I find is answers to know if the element already exists in the DOM (which would solve my problem, but that would be a way unprofessional to solve).

Here is my code ex :

```
function randomName(element) {
// Im trying to find some method like this:
  const result = isElement(element) ? true : false
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I check if an element exists in the visible DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-can-i-check-if-an-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom)

Comment: the question isn't duplicated. I made it clear that methods like this don't answer the question, they just solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check if the variable is an instance of [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). So basically

```js
function isElement(element){
    return element instanceof HTMLElement;
}
```

Also check the [mdn-docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), because it's possible that you want to check if your `element` is a `Node` (would include text-only nodes) or just an `Element` (that would include XML-tags in an XML document).